# IIS Redirect Module: Redirect based on HTTP_COOKIE

Tags: redirect, iis, cookies

We would like to set IIS Redirection for a URL based on HTTP_COOKIE

cookie-name is `_xx` and 
value is `HCjdskfds==`

It would look like below in the header values

`_xx=dfjdskfds==`

How do I redirect everything under `https://xxx.yyy.com/` to `https://zzz.kkk.com/` if the cookie value matches the above value?

Answer (score 0):

If cookie name is `_xx` and value is `HCjdskfds==`

You rule should be like that:

```
<rule name="redirect based by cookie" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_COOKIE}" pattern="_xx=HCjdskfds==" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="xxx.yyy.com" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://zzz.kkk.com/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

1. List item